# Control seconds SPI interface with SpiDev

Tags: raspbian, python, spi

Is there any option to control the second SPI interface of Raspberry Pi 2 B with SpiDev?

http://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi

Pin 19, 21, 23 are SPI0 and Pin 35, 38, 40 are SPI1.

SPI0 works perfect, but if I try to open SPI1 an IOError raises:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My code to open:

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(1,2) #for SPI1 CS2
spi.open(0,0) #for SPI0 CS0
```

In /dev/ there are also only 2 SPI files

```
/dev/spidev0.0
/dev/spidev0.1
```

But is there any option to use the second SPI interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit `/boot/config.txt`, add the following line, and reboot.

`dtoverlay=spi1-3cs`

You should then have the following devices.

```
$ ls /dev/sp*
/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1  /dev/spidev1.0  /dev/spidev1.1  /dev/spidev1.2
```

Then try the Python spidev module.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I only found answers which say that the second SPI interface is not usable.